# What is known about topological groups of countable spread in ZFC?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing, topological-groups

A topological space has *countable spread* if every discrete subspace is at most countable.

By Theorem 8.10 in Todorcevic's book "[Partition Problems in Topology](https://books.google.com.ua/books/about/Partition_Problems_in_Topology.html?id=k6UZnZ_qkgIC&redir_esc=y)", PFA implies that each regular space $X$ with countable spread is hereditarily Lindelof and hence has countable pseudocharacter (which means that each singleton $\{x\}$ in $X$ is a $G_\delta$-set). This result entails the following

**Corollary.** *Under PFA, each topological group of countable spread has countable pseudocharacter.*

> **Problem.** Is this corollary true in ZFC? In other words: *has each topological group of countable spread countable pseudocharacter?*

**Remark.** The [Peng-Wu example](https://settheory.mathtalks.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Peng.pdf) of an L-group shows that topological groups with countable spread need not be separable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no.

In the paper *"[A separable normal topological group need not be Lindelöf](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0016660X76900337)"* (General topology and its applications, 1976), Hajnal and Juhász use the continuum hypothesis to construct a hereditarily separable topological group $G$ which is not Lindelöf. They construct it as a dense subgroup of $2^{\omega_1}$ and it has many other properties (e.g. it is countably compact and hereditarily normal). It also has what they call in the paper property (P): for any $\alpha \in \omega_1$ the restriction map $2^{\omega_1} \to 2^\alpha$ maps $G$ onto the whole $2^\alpha$.

It is clear that hereditarily separable is stronger than countable spread and that property (P) implies uncountable pseudocharacter, so this $G$ is a counterexample for your corollary (under $CH$).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Maybe this group is a Borel image of a Polish space and hence it gives also a counterexample to this problem: https://mathoverflow.net/a/320637/61536 Or it is too optimistic?